# ORDER BY indexedColumn ridiculously slow when used with LIMIT on MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, order-by, limits

The MyISAM table has 4.5m rows. Query with just LIMIT returns fast; query with just ORDER BY returns fast; combining both it never finishes. I've also tried USE INDEX(indexedColumn, Latitude, Longitude), but it doens't help.

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN '29.187190582784076' AND '29.761053992852936' AND Longitude BETWEEN '-101.0597705588786' AND '-99.7414111838786') LIMIT 100;
```

89 rows; returns in 0.71 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN '29.187190582784076' AND '29.761053992852936' AND Longitude BETWEEN '-101.0597705588786' AND '-99.7414111838786') ORDER BY indexedColumn DESC;
```

89 rows, returns in 0.84 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN '29.187190582784076' AND '29.761053992852936' AND Longitude BETWEEN '-101.0597705588786' AND '-99.7414111838786') ORDER BY indexedColumn DESC LIMIT 100;
```

hasnt returned after several minutes

EXPLAIN ORDER BY with LIMIT

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys            | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Stuff | index | Latitude,Longitude       | indexedColumn| 5       | NULL | 9643 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

LIMIT ONLY

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key      | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stuff | range | Latitude,Longitude | Latitude | 30      | NULL | 81158 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

ORDER BY ONLY

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key      | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stuff | range | Latitude,Longitude | Latitude | 30      | NULL | 81158 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need MyISAM for full text search, and AWS RDS does not have the 5.6.4. I didn't try this with InnoDB.

I have also tried this on a MariaDB server and the outcome is the same. I increased the server memory size and didn't help.

I've also tried using spatial geometry instead of lat/lon doubles, and the outcome was the same.

Also tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff ORDER BY indexedColumn DESC LIMIT 100
```

100 rows; 0.06 sec

I used an AWS RDS with 4gb memory and increased key_buffer_size to 2gb. The indexes on table are 600mb. Perhaps there are other configurations I'm unaware of that aren't taking advantage of the memory, since RDS is mainly configured for InnoDB.

-------------EDIT---------------------

I created an 8GB AWS RDS MySQL instance with the data. I used ST_CONTAINS on spatial indexed point which returns in 1.1 second (which works for me).

I am still interested in knowing why the other queries have problems though. I feel like it's probably a configuration issue with limited RAM. I've done hundreds of queries like this and never run into a problem like this. Seems like a random fluke.

I'll try converting the MyISAM table to InnoDB to see if it matters.

Comment: For 4.5 million rows, you need the technique given in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the EXPLAINs it seems quite clear what happens - the "limit only" one uses index on latitude because it finds it most useful, then tries all found rows for longitude until it gathers 100 of them and quits.

The "order only" uses the same path, but does not stop after 100 because it needs all of them - it then sorts all matching rows by a filesort (I suppose only a small part of those 81k are returned so the sort is fast).

But the slow one (wrongly) uses ["order by .. limit" optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) - for some reason it thinks that lot of rows will satisfy the condition so goes by the `indexedColumn` order. But in reality there are too few matching ones so it walks a big part of the table before finding the 100 matching rows. That means that a big portion of the table needs to be read to memory from disk in the case the available memory is not big enough to contain it (or it was not loaded before).

The results - you actually do NOT want to use the index on `indexedColumn` as there are so few matching rows that sorting them "the slow way" is actually more effective than using the index. You can do that by `ignore index(indexedColumn)` and/or you can probably add a composite index over both `(Latitude, Longitude)`. That should return only few hundreds of rows and any operation on them will become trivial.

Comment: This worked; thanks jkavalik. What's sad is if the lat/lon query is bigger with the original query, the query is fast (like the whole US .02 sec). If I add IGNORE INDEX when viewing the whole US it takes 3.25 seconds. If I am viewing a small piece of land like in the original question, it doesn't finish unless I add IGNORE INDEX. I could measure the distance and decide whether or not to add IGNORE INDEX, or I could just roll with the spatial indexing which looks like it might be a bit slower.

Comment: @CalebPitman yes, its about the "selectivity" of the conditions - if many rows will match, finding 100 in the right order is easy, otherwise not. Did you try the composite index on lat/long? If it won't help in all cases then  `(indexedColumn, Latitude, Longitude)` might help a bit - it would be an index scan which might be better than a table scan in case the table has lot of columns - but that depends on if the available mysql version can use [index condition pushdown](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html).

Comment: @jkavalik, well put mate. Been following your answers for a short while. Ever thought of relocating to Amsterdam? We are looking to expand our DBA team.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your query in the following manner:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stuff FORCE INDEX(indexedColumn)
WHERE 
    (
        Latitude > '29.187190582784076' 
        AND Latitude < '29.761053992852936'
    ) 
    AND 
    (
        Longitude > '-101.0597705588786' 
        AND Longitude < '-99.7414111838786'
    ) 
ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Try the FORCE INDEX option and also try the nested greater than and less than and more verbose query instead of between and check the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion james. FORCE INDEX has to be placed after the table selection. eg. SELECT * FROM stuff FORCE INDEX(indexedColumn) WHERE (Latitude > '29.187190582784076' AND Latitude < '29.761053992852936') AND (Longitude > '-101.0597705588786' AND Longitude < '-99.7414111838786') ORDER BY indexedColumn DESC LIMIT 100;
Still, this has the same result as the other queries.

Comment: @CalebPitman ah yes, that's right about force index location. Sorry trying that version didn't help. Now it has me stumped.